# Running Cron in Django on AWS Elastic Beanstalk without .ebextensions

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a function to count daily active users within a Django application using cron.

All guides I can find seem to be many years old and they all reference using a .config file located within .ebextentions folder.

My app has been running fine for a while but I haven't actually got a .ebextensions folder so wondering if there's a bad config or if I'm just doing something obvious wrong.

**Problem:**

Trying to run cron jobs within Django application running on Elastic Beanstalk in AWS environment. Ideally all set up within code and pushed with "eb deploy" but happy for a more manual solution using command line on the linux instance itself.

**Attempted Solution**

Reading through AWS documentation and various online sources I have created a "my_cron.config" file inside a ".ebextensions" folder with the following content:

```
files:
    /usr/local/bin/my_cron_script.sh:
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
            source $PYTHONPATH/activate
            python3 /var/app/current/manage.py dailyCounts

    /etc/cron.d/my_cron:
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            0 6 00 * * root /usr/local/bin/my_cron_script.sh >> /var/log/my_cron.log 2>&1

commands:
  rm_old_cron:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

When running "eb deploy" I get the following error:

```
2023-03-18 14:27:56    ERROR   Updating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-XXXID-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-XXXID failed Reason: Unable to retrieve Endpoint.Address attribute for AWS::RDS::DBInstance, with error message DBInstance XXXID not found. (Service: Rds, Status Code: 404, Request ID: UUID-1234)
```

I have also tried the raw suggestion from AWS docs directly:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    jq: [] 

files:
  "/usr/local/bin/test_cron.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      INSTANCE_ID=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2>/dev/null`
      REGION=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document 2>/dev/null | jq -r .region`

      # Find the Auto Scaling Group name from the Elastic Beanstalk environment
      ASG=`aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" \
          --region $REGION --output json | jq -r '.[][] | select(.Key=="aws:autoscaling:groupName") | .Value'`

      # Find the first instance in the Auto Scaling Group
      FIRST=`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names $ASG \
          --region $REGION --output json | \
          jq -r '.AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[] | select(.LifecycleState=="InService") | .InstanceId' | sort | head -1`

      # If the instance ids are the same exit 0
      [ "$FIRST" = "$INSTANCE_ID" ]

  "/usr/local/bin/cron_example.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      /usr/local/bin/test_cron.sh || exit
      # Now run commands that should run on only 1 instance.
      echo "Cron running at "`date` > /tmp/cron_example.log

  "/etc/cron.d/cron_example":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/cron_example.sh

commands:
  rm_old_cron:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/cron_example.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

This throws a "null" error that I can't seem to find an answer for online either.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here or are there better solution out there using something like Django_cron instead?

Thanks for the advice.